Roughness and Normal not affecting one surface, but it does the other
I have two objects, but only one of them is affected by the roughness and normal input.
Here is the file with packed resources: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgyMJwcFicenlLUh2LgPix9Hu0KCoQ?e=NFjfvx


I looked at this post but the solution didn't help.  I've compared every possible setting between the objects and can't find the difference.  Any help?

Your objects have 2 different materials but these materials are almost similar, so the problem doesn't come from here, actually your problem comes from the fact that it is not correctly unwprapped, for example unwrap with the Project from View option and you'll see the wooden pattern.

That worked.  Thank you.  If anyone needs help with this I found directions around the 6 minute point in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHlyg6j-5Gg
